# Generate overlapping gapped-kmer from strings

Tags: python

I have a string like `HDHDJDUEUEUD`, which I would like to make all gapped kmers out of with a given k and m (number of maximum gap between).

For example with `k=3` and `m =2`, we have two subsequences of length three, separated by a gap (can be represented as a period) of length 0, 1, or 2 like the following:

HDHDJD, HDH.JDU, HDH..DUE, DHDJDU, etc

How can this be done in an efficient way? I have a list of over 1 million sequences to perform this operation on.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_kmers(sequence, k, m):
  """
  Get the k-mers (given as 'k') and put '.' (given as 'm') as gap between each kmer and the next kmer
  while also moving one index for each '.'.
  """
  n = len(sequence)
  m = m + 1
  kmers = []

  # Get the k-mers * 2
  for i in range(n - (k * 2) + 1):
    full_kmer = sequence[i:i + k * 2]
    kmers.append(full_kmer)

    # Extend the k-mers list with the '.' gaps
    for gap in range(1, m):
      extended_kmer = sequence[i:i + k] + '.' * gap + sequence[i + k + gap:i + k + m + gap]
      kmers.append(extended_kmer)

  # Print the kmers
  print(kmers)

# Example
seq = "HDHDJDUEUEUD"
k = 3
m = 2

seq_kmers_gaps = find_kmers(seq, k, m)
print(seq_kmers_gaps)
```

results:

```
['HDHDJD', 'HDH.JDU', 'HDH..DUE', 'DHDJDU', 'DHD.DUE', 'DHD..UEU', 'HDJDUE', 'HDJ.UEU', 'HDJ..EUE', 'DJDUEU', 'DJD.EUE', 'DJD..UEU', 'JDUEUE', 'JDU.UEU', 'JDU..EUD', 'DUEUEU', 'DUE.EUD', 'DUE..UD', 'UEUEUD', 'UEU.UD', 'UEU..D']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for letting me know, I'll make sure to edit this answer and improve my next answers.